# ExtJS TreeGrid Groups

Tags: javascript, grid, grouping, extjs4, treegrid

Is it possible in ExtJS 4 to have a TreeGrid with grouped rows based on a particular column value, much like you can with the normal Grid control?

Answer (score 0):

It works just like on the grid, using plugins grouping. But the result would be a bit weird, just try it out